# how to access array in jquery

Tags: jquery

The array is somewhat like this :

```
[[Object { button={...}}, 
  Object { input={...}}, 
  Object { checkbox={...}}, 
  Object { textarea={...}}],
 [Object { textarea={...}}]
]
```

In the curly brackets i have set some properties like color,value,type etc.
What i want is to get the each object of  an array and check through the properties like type of an object and then call a function to perform further things. Just like in PHP we use :

```
foreach($a as $b){
 // and then do something here ..
};
```

Kindly help me through and i hope everyone can understand what i am trying to say.

```js
// var i is the counter for page numbers   
function pagination(i) {
  alert(i);
  i--;
  //page is array 

  var result = page;
  //console.log(result[i]);
  var $currentElem;
  $(result[i]).each(function() {

    currentElem = $(this);
    console.log(currentElem);

  });
}
```

Comment: How does your `page` array look like? Can you show us an example? And what are you trying to do to the array? It doesn't come across as obvious in your question.

Comment: page array contain objects with their properties(as shown at the start)  what i want from it to read array in jquery and access the objects in it

Comment: I mean, an **example** of your data, i.e. dummy array. That is also why we emphasise on posting minimal, verifiable and concrete examples, instead of pseudo-code that does not work.

Comment: its actually encoded in JSON 
[[{"button":{"type":"","color":"white","width":"15px","backgroundcolor":"white","value":" My Button","control":"button","name":"","label":"My Button","status":"","style":"","left":"","center":"","right":""}},{"input":{"type":"","color":"white","width":"15px","label":"Enter your text...","control":"textinput","name":"","status":"","style":"","left":"","center":"","right":""}}],[{"checkbox":{"type":"","fontcolor":"white","label":"My Checkbox","control":"checkbox","name":"","status":"","style":"","left":"","center":"","right":""}}]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.each` is used when you're looping over the elements of a jQuery collection. To loop over the contents of an array or object. use `$.each()`:

```
$.each(result[i], function(n, currentElem) {
    console.log(currentElem);
});
```

And you shouldn't use `$(this)` unless `this` is a DOM element. If it's just a Javascript object, wrapping it in a jQuery object is unnecessary.

You can access the properties using the normal Javascript `variable.propertyname` syntax, e.g. `currentElem.button` and `currentElem.button.color`. To append elements to your view, you can do something like:

```
var button = currentElem.button;
$("<button>", {
    value: button.value,
    name: button.name,
    css: {
        color: button.color,
        width: button.width,
        backgroundColor: button.backgroundcolor
    }
}).appendTo($("#buttonDiv");
```

Comment: yes barmar thanks but the next part is am having problem yes i get the objects of an array but i want to access these object and its properties can you help me with that @barmar

Comment: `variable.propertyname` will access a property in the object that `variable` contains.

Comment: i want to get the object for example if its a button i would call a function that would append button to my view . i hope iam making sense and you can get what i want @barmar

Comment: yes i can get the property now thanks for your help :) @barmar

Comment: I've added an example of creating a button.

Comment: $.each(result[i], function(n, currentElem) {
    console.log(currentElem);
 console.log(currentElem.button.color);
 if(currentElem == "button")
 {
  alert("accomplished");
 
 }
 else 
 {
  alert("not again ");
 }

Comment: yes i can access the properties but i want a scenario like above to check if the object is button then append button else do something.. @barmar

Comment: You can use `if(currentElem.button)` to tell if it's a button.

Comment: yes thanks alot @barmar :) you made my day better thank you

Answer (score 1):

To iterate you can use for(in) or in jquery $.each.

```
for(var i in array) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: i have no experience with $.each so that if you can help me it would be of great help thanks

Comment: Use for(in). Is the same and you don't need jquery. If you need jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: `for-in` shouldn't be used with arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea